# Wix : Is there any way to proceed with installation based on items selected :

Tags: wix

I have scenario where i would like to have drop down menu . Items in menu will be name of region and language like **en_US , da_DK** . Based on item selected in drop down menu , i will proceed with installation of DLLs of that region . How to implement this functionality in Wix .

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx45'/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id='OfficeToolRunTime'/>
  <MsiPackage
    Id='FM1'
    DisplayInternalUI='yes'
    SourceFile="1.msi" />
  <MsiPackage
    Id='FM2'
    DisplayInternalUI='yes'
    SourceFile="2.msi" />
</Chain>
```

In above wix code i want conditional installation of msi ( 1.msi or 2.msi ) based on os locale

Comment: Language code "da-DA" does not exist, as "DA" is not a valid [country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Decoding_table). Did you mean "da-DK"?

Comment: yes . da-Dk , fr-FR , de-DE like that